# Why do I get this error and how do I fix it? - Python email script

Tags: python, email

I keep getting the following error:

`error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

Does anybody have any suggestions on what might be causing the error, and how to fix this?

```
import smtplib

msg = "\nHello!\nThe following servers have an error........" 
# The /n separates the message from the headers



server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) ## Try 587 or 2525

    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()

    #Next, log in to the server
    try:
        server.login("useremail", "password")

        print " you are logged into your account"
    except:
        print "Username or password is incorrect" 

    #Send the mail

    try:
        server.sendmail("useremail", "recipient", msg)
        print "Congratulations! Email was sent." 
    except:
        print "email could not send"


        server.close()
```

Comment: add `except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError as e:print e`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to send a simple email with [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail), it could be saved by the default settings:

```
import yagmail
yagmail.SMTP('username', 'password').send(contents = msg)
```

You might have to install it first using:

```
pip install yagmail # (Python 2) or 
pip3 install yagmail # for Python 3
```